# Sentinel 2 SE data export

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am new to GEE and sharing my GEE code for NDVI derivation. Actually, I am trying to export my NDVI image to my drive and found out that large area size error.

How can I make my code select the particular image to perform NDVI rather that using the average mean value date (ranges given in the code)?

The code is as follows:

```
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2018-12-15', '2018-12-18')
                  .filterBounds(region)
                  .map(function(image){return image.clip(region)}) 
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',5))
                  .map(maskS2clouds);
var count = dataset.size();
print('Count: ', count);
print('All metadata:', dataset);
var visualization = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};
var addNDVI = function(dataset) {
  var ndvi = dataset.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return dataset.addBands(ndvi);
};
var S2_NDVI = dataset.map(addNDVI);
var NDVIpalette = ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301'];
Map.addLayer(S2_NDVI.select('NDVI'), {palette: NDVIpalette}, 'NDVI');
Map.centerObject(region);
Map.addLayer(dataset.mean(), visualization, 'RGB');

Export.image.toDrive({
    image:S2_NDVI.toBands(), 
    description: 'ndvi',
    folder: 'NDVI',
    region: region.geometry,
    scale: 10,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing the value of the argument [maxPixels](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting#maxpixels) in your export function:

```js
Export.image.toDrive({
    image:S2_NDVI.toBands(), 
    description: 'ndvi',
    folder: 'NDVI',
    region: region.geometry,
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 40e9
});
```